# Как записать значение массива в переменную?

Tags: c#, wpf

Хочу вот такое значение поместить в переменную и вывести это значение[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но что бы я не делал выводит либо System.Byte[]

Либо непонятную абру кадабру

```
var arrya = App.DataBase.Books.Select(p => new
        {
            p.ElectronicVersion
        }).ToList();



        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var a in arrya)
        {
            if (a.ElectronicVersion != null)

                stringBuilder.Append(a.ElectronicVersion);
        }

        MessageBox.Show(stringBuilder.ToString());


        MessageBox.Show(string.Concat(App.DataBase.Books.Select(i => i.ElectronicVersion)));
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 var arrya = App.DataBase.Books.Select(p => new
        {
            V = p.ElectronicVersion.ToString(),
        }).ToList();


        Convert.ToString(arrya);

        MessageBox.Show(arrya.ToString());
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какой тип данных у ElectronicVersion, байтовый массив `byte[]`? Если это байтовый массив, то вы должны сначала перевести его в строку.

Comment: @AlexKrass, а как правильно конвертировать ? Я выше добавил как сделал , вот ещё **var arrya = App.DataBase.Books.Select(p => new
            {
                V = Convert.ToString(p.ElectronicVersion)
            }).ToList();**

Тоже не конвертируется

Comment: Хорошо бы показать как это поле выглядит в классе. Если это действительно `byte[]`, то через `Encoding.Default.GetString(p.ElectronicVersion)`, иногда могут быть проблемы с кодировкой и надо вместо Default выбирать конкретную.

Comment: @AlexKrass,  UTF8, UTF7, UTF32, Unicode, Default,  BigEndianUnicode,  ASCII  все перепробовал, и все бросают одно и тоже исключение скриншот выше

Comment: `Convert.ToHexString(p.ElectronicVersion)`